# GPO: Different GPOs for different users on different PCs

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, organizational-unit

I would like to ask you, how to achieve having different GPO's for different user OUs on different PCs. I'm still a bit new to this. It's running Windows Server 2012 R2.

To understand our OU structure, here is an image:
[OU structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0T5z.png)

As an example, I will talk about Disabling Task Manager. The thing is, that users from Departments OU are logging to their own workstations as well as RDS server. I need to allow them to have the Task manager on their workstations, but not on RDS. Same goes for Remote users, which log mostly to RDS and should not have Task manager.
But then there are Power users, which should have Task manager both on their workstation and on RDS. But also I need them to run a script, if they log into a workstation, not RDS.

I know that to disable Task manager on RDS for Departments OU I could use Loopback processing, but I got quite confused how to achieve having different GPO for Power users. Do I need to put  them to separate Security Groups, make two GPO's with Loopback processing, and separate them using Security filtering? Or is there another approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a GPO that target **User** configuration, to prevent it to apply to some type of operating it can be achieved in a simpler method than loopback processing with a WMI filter.

Use a WMI filter.

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE ProductType = 3
```

> To restrict the query to only clients or only servers, add a clause
>   that includes the ProductType parameter. To filter for client
>   operating systems only, such as Windows 7 or Windows Vista, use only
>   ProductType="1". For server operating systems that are not domain
>   controllers, use ProductType="3". For domain controllers only, use
>   ProductType="2". This is a useful distinction, because you often want
>   to prevent your GPOs from being applied to the domain controllers on
>   your network.

From there link the GPO to an OU of where your user are and/or remove authentified user and select a security group.

The WMI filter will make a condition, if it return **true**, then the GPO is applied if the user is in the correct OU and is in the security group if you set one.

[Some reference there](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947846(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. This is actually pretty good, I didn't know about the ProductType, this would work for me. By any chance, do you know about some way to display all the possible tables and columns with info I can use in this SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit confusing but maybe I can help with a few rules.  GPO are applied in order, so whatever GPO gets applied last wins. I.E.  If you turn it on in one policy and turn it off in another which ever was appled last is the policy that is going to take effect.  GPO's can be either machine or user based.  So if you apply a Task Manager Policy, which I believe is user based you would need to first apply the policy to all standard users to turn it off then have another policy to turn it back on for your power users.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Create a new security group, add the users to the group, then create a GPO and add the new group as local Users on the Workstations (check the following Link to add security groups to specific local groups) http://www.expta.com/2011/02/adding-users-to-local-security-groups.html

On the same GPO, add the following (By Registry Key) to Enable Task Manager and assign the new GPO to the Workstations OU.

To Enable Task Manager:

REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Create another GPO (By Registry Key) to Disable Task Manager and assign the new GPO to RDS OU.
To Disable Task Manager:

REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

Comment: Thank you for an anwser. I have done something slightly different because I needed to set other policies and preferences for those users, not only Task manager, so actually I created a security group, added the users to it. Then I created a GPO to restrict those users, put this GPO to OU with RDS servers, enabled loopback processing and I have set Security filtering only to the RDS servers and this security group, which works quite well for far.